# because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I have implemented following generic model as base model and two models derived from it and i need one to many relationship. I have used fluent api to create the relationships but i get the error mentioned in the title.
Would you please see if you find any thing wrong in my code.

```
 public abstract class ModelBase<T> : BaseEntity, IModelBase<T>
{
    public virtual T Id { get; set; }
}

 [Table("VehicleModel", Schema = "Tracker")]
public class VehicleModelModel : ModelBase<int>
{
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public byte LiPerKM { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<VehicleModel> Vehicles { get; set; }

 [Table("Vehicle", Schema = "Tracker")]
public class VehicleModel : ModelBase<Guid>
{
    public string VehicleName { get; set; }
    public string LicensePlate { get; set; }
    public int VehicleModelId { get; set; }
    public virtual VehicleModelModel Model { get; set; }
    public virtual TrackerModel Tracker { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual DriverModel Driver { get; set; }

modelBuilder.Entity<VehicleModel>()
                    .HasRequired<VehicleModelModel>(s => s.Model)
                    .WithMany(s => s.Vehicles)
                    .HasForeignKey(s => s.VehicleModelId);
```

Here I get this error:

```
entity types 'VehicleModelModel' and 'VehicleModel' cannot share table 'VehicleModels' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them.
```